# Mocha breakpoints using Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, mocha.js, tdd

Is it possible to add breakpoints to Mocha tests using Visual Studio Code?

Normally when debugging code, one needs to configure the launch.json, setting the program attribute to the Javascript file to execute. I am not sure how to do this for Mocha though.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

**Did you know, that you just go into your launch config, put your cursor after or between your other configs and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd> to get a current, valid mocha config auto-generated?**

Which works perfectly fine for me. Including stopping at breakpoints.
( I also had a prior, now outdated one, that did no longer for various setting-related reasons. )

[image]

As of VSCode 1.21.1 (March 2018) this yields:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Mocha (Test single file)",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/mocha",
        "--inspect-brk",
        "${relativeFile}",
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "port": 9229
    }
}
```

On a side-note: `debug-brk` [is deprectated](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32529) (for anyone with Node >= Version 8 at least).

Comment: I had some custom code needed to initialize the document and disable Hot Module Replacement. Pass this argument in the `"args"` block: `"--require", "${workspaceFolder}/tools/testSetup.js",`

Comment: VS Code 1.29.1: The `Ctrl+Space` autogenerated Mocha Tests config did not have `debug-brk`. Despite that debugging with breakpoints worked just fine.

Comment: @Antony Yes, for long `debug-brk` it is no longer needed used, supported or auto-inserted. My _side-note_ only clarified this, as multiple other answers mention it.

Comment: I had to insert a comma after the right brace of my (only) other configuration for `ctrl + space` to work.

Comment: Control-space had no effect, but the actual configuration snippet worked. For newcomers - to get the file to put the snippet in in the first place, first open your project directory with File -> Open. Then go back to the debugging view and press the gear icon to create launch.json, where you can paste the snippet. Then set breakpoints by clicking to the left of line numbers, select your file to run and try the green play icon to the left of the gear icon.

Comment: For an up-to-date example of proper configuration for Mocha see: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/debugging-mocha-tests

Comment: Just wanted to throw out there that the new "pwa-node" type is somewhat necessary for debugging mocha internals with newer versions of mocha and VSCode

Comment: FYI, the accepted answer @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/55883516/684271 reveals what had to be removed as of Nov 2020.

Answer (score 73):

If you don't want to use `--debug-brk`+Attach or state an absolute path to your global mocha installation (which will brake if you keep your launch.json under version control and have multiple developers on different machines), install mocha as a dev dependency and add this to your launch.json:

```
{
  "name": "mocha",
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
  "stopOnEntry": false,
  "args": ["--no-timeouts", "--colors"], //you can specify paths to specific tests here
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "runtimeExecutable": null,
  "env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "testing"
  }
}
```

Full debugging support in your tests by just pressing F5.

`--no-timeouts` makes sure your tests don't time out because you stopped at a breakpoint, and `--colors` makes sure Mocha outputs colors even though it doesn't detect that VS Code supports colors.

Comment: For anyone else having trouble. Note the _mocha and not mocha. With only mocha it will run the tests in VS code but the breakpoints are not hit

Comment: For those using TypeScript, this is a suitable answer so long as you set `sourceMaps: true`. Thanks a billion!

Comment: To add your npm compatible custom test params, add something like `npm_config_myparam` to the env block. Where on the CLI, it might look like `npm --myparam=myvalue test`.

Answer (score 45):

Another way is to use the `--debug-brk` command line option of mocha and the default `Attach` launch setting of the Visual Studio Code debugger.

---

Suggested deeper explanation (from André)

To do this:

Run mocha from the command line using this command:

```
mocha --debug-brk
```

Now in VS Code click on the Debug icon, then select `Attach` from the option next to the start button. Add breakpoints in VS Code and then click start.

Comment: This way is much easier, there's virtually no configuration

Comment: You must add `"request": "attach"` to the launch.json if it doesn't exist - otherwise it will complain that you must specify a program or some other error.

Comment: This seems to be `VS Code` specific. Doesn't work in normal VS 2015

Comment: great advice Thanks :)

Comment: Note, that `--debug-brk` is [nowadays deprecated](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32529),  that's why I suggest [auto-creating a fresh debug config in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46977963/444255), yes, alslo specifically for mocha.

Comment: this worked for me however i had first changed my vscode config per this article first https://itnext.io/the-absolute-easiest-way-to-debug-node-js-with-vscode-2e02ef5b1bad unsure if that helps anyone

Answer (score 26):

I've made this work on VSCode on OS X 10.10. Just replace your `./settings/launch.json` file with this.

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run app.js",
            "type": "node",
            "program": "app.js", // Assuming this is your main app file.
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [],
            "cwd": ".",
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            "env": { "NODE_ENV": "production"}
        },
        {
            "name": "Run mocha",
            "type": "node",
            "program": "/Users/myname/myfolder/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": ["test/unit.js"],
            "cwd": ".",
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            "env": { "NODE_ENV": "production"}
        }
    ]
}
```

It is also available as a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/paambaati/54d33e409b4f7cf059cc).

The key values you need to change are `program`, which should be set to the `_mocha` executable, and `args`, which should be an array of your test files.

Comment: Doesn't work for me (on windows) - but seems like a good solution if it works :)

Comment: Yes. Sorry

`OpenDebug process has terminated unexpectedly`

Comment: Can you try setting `"runtimeExecutable"` to `"C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe"` or wherever Node is installed?

Comment: For sure - but no change.

Comment: I don't use Windows, so I can't help any further. However, keep an eye on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30002073/398713) - they're talking about this OpenDebug issue.

Comment: On Windows, I run this but the breakpoints are ignored. I set stopOnEntry to true, so VSCode will let me step through code. However, if I hit F5, mocha run nonstop, showing the expected results in the console, but it completely ignores my breaks.

Answer (score 15):

1. Go to `Debug > Add Configuration...` menu
2. Select `Node.js` environment
3. Select `Mocha Tests` option from the appeared drop-down list
4. Type the path of your test file as the last item of the `args` property
5. Add a `breakpoint`
6. Click on `Debug` icon
7. Select `Mocha Tests` as a configuration
8. Press `Start debugging` button
9. :-)

Answer (score 12):

The way I got it to work on VS Code (1.8.2) on Mac OS X is:

```
{
    "name": "Mocha",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "args": ["--recursive"], //you can specify paths to specific tests here
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "runtimeExecutable": null,
    "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "testing"
    }
}
```

Mocha needs to be installed in the npm modules directory.

Comment: This had me stuck for ages. I incorrectly used the path from "which mocha" rather than node_modules. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I've figured out a way to do this which I classify as a *workaround*. I expect the Visual Studio Code team to provide a more definitive solution for this but meanwhile this what I've done:

1. I've created a `./settings/mocha.js` file which runs mocha programatically passing arguments as a list of files to be run. You can see the full file [here](https://github.com/appscot/sails-orientdb/blob/dd7f83289502c5bbf3e664cd0035ff434f9d8de2/.settings/mocha.js);
2. I've created a launch config which will run the `./settings/mocha.js` as the `program` and passes the files/file patterns we need to test as arguments:

   ```
   {
       "name": "Unit tests",
       "type": "node",
       "program": ".settings/mocha.js",
       "stopOnEntry": true,
       "args": ["test/unit/*.js", "test/unit/**/*.js"],
       "cwd": ".",
       "runtimeExecutable": null,
       "env": { }
   }
   ```

   [Full launch.json example](https://github.com/appscot/sails-orientdb/blob/dd7f83289502c5bbf3e664cd0035ff434f9d8de2/.settings/launch.json#L24-L34)

So this is the equivalent of doing `mocha test/unit/*.js test/unit/**/*.js` and now we can use breakpoints in our mocha tests.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, it can't find the test files, paths are correct I tried also with full paths.

Comment: This works for me too vscode 0.10.6. With breakpoints in .ts files, with sourcemaps, I did add `'sourceMaps': true, 'outDir': './build'` to my launch configuration.

Answer (score 4):

If you add ${file} variable at the end of the args list you can start debugging directly from the file you have open:

```
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Mocha Tests",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
            "args": [
                "-u",
                "tdd",
                "--timeout",
                "999999",
                "--colors",
                "${file}"
            ],
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for adding yet another answer, but none of the previous ones quite worked for me as of VS Code 1.8.1 and the standard Node debugger included in it. Here is the way I solved it (with guidance from the previous answers here and from the official [VS Code Node.js Debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/node-debugging) docs) so there is one click/keypress debugging:

- Ensure mocha is installed as a `devDependency` in `packages.json`: `"devDependencies": { "mocha": "^3.2", ... }`
- Run `npm install` in the directory of your `package.json` to make sure mocha is now installed in `node_modules/`
- Open `.vscode/launch.json` (or in VS Code, press F1, start typing "launch", and select "Debug: Open launch.json")
- Click the blue "Add Configuration" button in the bottom right (or just copy and paste one of your others); this step is optional... I mean, you can re-use an existing config. But I suggest adding one to keep it less confusing.
- Change the following in your `launch.json`, then pick the new config name in the debug window in VS Code and click the green arrow to start debugging your node + mocha tests!

In the new config in `launch.json:`

```
"configurations": [{
    "name": "whatever name you want to show in the VS Code debug list",
    "type": "node",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha",
    "args": ["--debug-brk=5858", "--no-timeouts", "--colors", "test/**/*.js"],
    "address": "localhost",
    "port": 5858,
    // the other default properties that are created for you are fine as-is
}, ...]
```

This assumes the pattern `test/**/*.js` will work for where you put your tests. Change as appropriate.

Feel free to change the port as long as you change it in both of the `args` and `port` properties to match.

The key differences for me was making sure mocha was in `node_modules`, using `program` to point to the executable, and `args` needing `debug-brk=x` pointing to the port specified in `port`. The rest of the above just makes things prettier and easier.

It's up to you and your team if you put `.vscode/launch.json` in the repository or not. It's an IDE-only file, but your whole team could use it like this, no problem, since all paths and installs are relative and explicit.

Tip: The `package.json` can include a `scripts` tag that also launches mocha with something like `"test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha"`, but it is not used by VS Code—instead it is used when `npm test` is run at the command line. This one confused me for a bit. Noting it here in case others get confused too.

EDIT: VS Code 1.9.0 has added an "Add Configuration" option in the debug configuration drop-down, and you can pick "Node.js Mocha Tests" which help simplify most of the above. You still need to make sure mocha is in your `node_modules` and might have to update the `cwd` and last `runtimeArgs` (which is the pattern for finding your tests) to point to the appropriate paths. But once you set those two properties, it should work pretty much from there.

Answer (score 2):

in the launch.json, add 1 more configuration below

```
{
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Mocha Tests",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
      "args": [
        "--timeout",
        "10000",
        "${workspaceRoot}/services/*.spec.js",
        "${workspaceRoot}/*.spec.js"
      ],
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
    },
```

if you need to configure node version, simply add `runtimeExecutable` field like this

```
{
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Mocha Tests",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
      "args": [
        "--timeout",
        "10000",
        "${workspaceRoot}/services/*.spec.js",
        "${workspaceRoot}/*.spec.js"
      ],
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${env:HOME}/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/bin/node"
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Go to

> .vscode

then

> launch.json

file

2) Add the following configuration in launch.json -

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Mocha Test",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/*folder_path_containing_test*/node_modules/.bin/mocha",
            "windows": {
                "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/*folder_path_containing_test*/node_modules/.bin/mocha.cmd"
            },
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--colors",
                "--recursive",
                "${workspaceRoot}/*folder_path_till_test*/tests"
            ],
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/*folder_path_to_test*/app.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

3) Set breakpoints in test file and then press `F5`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using Windows. If you have installed mocha globally then setting program to the following path worked for me (swap in your username).

```
"program": "C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\mocha\\bin\\_mocha"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working fro me on a Windows 7 machine.  I do have mocha installed globally, but this configuration is pointing to the project install to avoid the need for a user profile path (which btw, I tried used %USERPROFILE% variable with no success).  I'm able to set breakpoints in my mocha tests now.  Yay!

```
{
        "name": "Mocha Tests",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "args": ["./test/**/*.js"],
        "runtimeExecutable": null,
        "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For those that are using grunt or gulp, the configuration is pretty simple.

Launch.json

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "name": "Run mocha by grunt",
        "type": "node",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "args": ["mochaTest"],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "runtimeExecutable": null
    }
]}
```

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
    mochaTest: {
        test: {
            options: {
                reporter: 'spec'
            },
            src: ['test/**/*test.js']
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-test');

grunt.registerTask('default', 'mochaTest');};
```

Answer (score 1):

In VSCode version 1.13.0 (macOS), they have it built-in under configurations -> `Mocha Tests`.

Comment: Same in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

When using Babel, or generating javascript files yet placing breakpoints in the source - you have to make sure to enable `sourceMaps` and define `outFiles`. Here's an example config that worked for me.

```
    {
        "name": "Mocha Test",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/packages/api/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/packages/api",
        "args": ["--colors", "--no-timeouts", "out/test"],
        "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/packages/api/out/*"],
        "sourceMaps": true,
    },
```

Note - you'll need to modify `outFiles` to include everything you might want to add a breakpoint to. This can be more tedious when in a monorepo and multiple dependent projects.

Answer (score 1):

The official [microsoft/vscode-recipes](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/debugging-mocha-tests) on Github has this `launch.json` for debugging mocha tests (enter the link for more mocha tests configurations):

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Mocha All",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
        "args": [
            "--timeout",
            "999999",
            "--colors",
            "${workspaceFolder}/test"
        ],
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Mocha Current File",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
        "args": [
            "--timeout",
            "999999",
            "--colors",
            "${file}"
        ],
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using TypeScript, the following configuration works for me in Visual Studio Code 0.8.0 (tsc 1.5.3)

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "build",
        "declaration": false
    },
    "files": [
        "./src/index.ts",
        "./src/test/appTests.ts"
    ]
}
```

The important things to note here is that source maps are generated and that the output directory for the js is set to `build`

`launch.json`

```
    {
        "name": "Attach",
        "type": "node",
        // TCP/IP address. Default is "localhost".
        "address": "localhost",
        // Port to attach to.
        "port": 5858,
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "outDir": "build"
    }
```

Please note that `sourceMaps` is set to `true` and that the `outDir` is set to `build`

**to debug**

1. Stick breakpoints in `index.ts` any other imported typescript file
2. Open a terminal and run : `mocha --debug-brk ./build/test/appTests.js`
3. From VSC, run the 'Attach' launch configuration

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of [launch configuration (launch.json)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-samples/blob/master/node-express-javascript/.vscode/launch.json) from Microsoft, which works with Mocha and allows using the debugger.

Also, there is a [description](https://scottaddie.com/2015/10/22/debugging-mocha-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-code/) of how to use the --debug-brk option.

Finally, here is an [alternative version of how to debug code with Mocha tests](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/running-mocha-tests-with-visual-studio-code) using tasks.json file of VS Code and Gulp task runner.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some dependency in the test it is also easy to attach it.

For example, I am using `mongo-unit-helper` to also have unit tests integrated with Database.

`package.json` script is: `mocha --recursive --require ./test/mongo-unit-helper.js --exit"`

My `launch.json` looks like:

```
  "configurations": [
  {
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Mocha Tests",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
  "args": [
    "-u",
    "tdd",
    "--timeout",
    "999999",
    "--colors",
    "--recursive",
    "--require",
    "${workspaceFolder}/test/mongo-unit-helper.js",
    "${workspaceFolder}/test/**/*.js",
  ],
  "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
 }
]
```

Solution is to put `--require` separately in `args` in `launch.json`.

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest solution**

Add the following code to the launch.json inside the .vscode folder :

```
{
            "name": "Unit tests",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
            "args": [
            ],
        }
```

You might want however to add a timeout argument as well:

```
 {
            "name": "Unit tests",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
            "args": [
                "--timeout",
                "999999"
            ],
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I had this problem when using a monorepo (e.g. `/repo/sub-repo`) which had a subfolder with a package.json and its own mocha configuration, but was launching mocha in the debugger from the root folder rather than the sub-folder. Switching to the sub-folder and creating a mocha configuration there solved the problem completely.